# wxPython not binding callbacks to events properly

Tags: python, wxpython, closures

Here's a roughly minimal demonstrative example:

```
import wx

app = wx.App(False)
frame = wx.Frame(None)

menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
menu = wx.Menu()
menuBar.Append(menu, "&Menu")
frame.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

for name in ['foo','bar','baz']:
    menuitem = menu.Append(-1,"&"+name,name)
    def menuclick(e):
        print(name)
    frame.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, menuclick, menuitem)

frame.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

The issue is that every menu item, when clicked, prints "baz".  Shouldn't the `menuclick` function wrap up the appropriate name in its closure and keep the original name around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the for loop `name` will be "baz", it's value will not go back in time to when you bound the `menuclick` to the menu event.

You can get to the menu item name via the event itself like this:

```
def menuclick(e):
    print(menu.FindItemById(e.Id).Label)
```

Comment: Hm, apparently I need to read up on Python closures. Thanks for the pointer on getting the label from the event!

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, by I'm not sure why this works where the inner-def version doesn't:

```
from functools import partial

def onclick(name,e):
    print(name)

for name in ['foo','bar','baz']:
    menuitem = menu.Append(-1,"&"+name,name)
    frame.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, partial(onclick,name), menuitem)
```

Comment: It works because partial remebers (makes a copy of) the value of the name in the moment it is called.